# Raising an index of a tensor while keeping the name of the index unchanged

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry

I would like to express a tensor $T^{\mu\nu}$ in terms of $T_{\mu\nu}$. I know that one can raise and lower indices of a tensor using the metric tensor $g_{\mu\nu}$ and its inverse:
$$T^{\mu\nu}=g^{\mu\alpha}T_{\alpha}^{\nu}$$
The problem is, this changes name of an index. Can I do something like
$$T^{\mu\nu}=g^{\mu\mu}g^{\nu\nu}T_{\mu\nu}$$
or do I have to do
$$T^{\mu\nu}=\frac{dx^{\mu}}{dx^{\alpha}}\frac{dx^{\nu}}{dx^{\beta}}g^{\mu\alpha}g^{\nu\beta}T_{\mu\nu}?$$

Comment: You'll just have to relabel indices before or after your calculation. People often do that without even mentioning they did so. I like to use names I dislike first, so the raising or lowering immediately switches to the names I want.

Answer (score 1):

Neither of these makes sense. On the left $\mu$ is a free variable, whereas on the right it occurs both as a free variable and as a bound variable (which is perhaps not obvious because of the summation convention but becomes clear when you explicitly write the summation over $\mu$). There’s no way to do this with just one raising, even if you allow a free variable to be re-used as a bound variable (which in my view is very bad style), because they would both have to appear on the same $g$ and there’d be no way to see which is which. However, if you’re really hell-bent on doing this, you can do it with raising, then lowering, then raising:

$$
T^{\mu\nu}=\sum_{\alpha}g^{\mu\alpha}\sum_\beta g_{\alpha\beta}\sum_\mu g^{\beta\mu}T_{\mu}^{\nu}\;,
$$

where the explicit sum notation clarifies which instance of $\mu$ is a bound variable being summed over and which one is free. But if you write this using the summation convention, it becomes ambiguous again:

$$
T^{\mu\nu}=g^{\mu\alpha}g_{\alpha\beta}g^{\beta\mu}T_{\mu}^{\nu}\;.
$$